# Convergence in mean square implies convergence in mean

Tags: probability-theory, proof-verification

Let X and $X_1, X_2, ...$ be random variables on $(\Omega, F, P)$
Show that if $X_n \rightarrow X$ in $L^2$ as $n$ $ \rightarrow \infty$ then $X_n \rightarrow X$ in $L^1$ as well.

I'm trying to prove this without using the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality, this is what I've got so far.

Convergence in $L^2$ implies that $\mathbb{E}[|X_n - X|^2] \rightarrow 0$ as $n \rightarrow \infty$.

I know that $|\mathbb{E}[X_n] - \mathbb{E}[X]]| = |\mathbb{E}[(X_n - X)]| \leq \mathbb{E}[|X_n - X|] \leq \mathbb{E}[|X_n - X|^2]$

Is it enough to say that as the $\lim_{n\to\infty} \mathbb{E}[|X_n - X|^2] = 0$
then this would imply that $\lim_{n\to\infty} \mathbb{E}[|X_n - X|] = 0$, and then convergence in mean square implies convergence in mean?

Also, how could I use the fact that $ 0 \leq Var(X) = \mathbb{E}[X^2]-\mathbb{E}[X]^2 = \mathbb{E}[(X - \mathbb{E}[X])^2]$ to prove it?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: The inequality $\Bbb E[|X_n - X|] \leq \Bbb E[|X_n - X|^2]$ is wrong. However, if you take $X = X_n - X$(unfortunately the variables have the same name!) in the fact on the last line, you will get something that corrects this inequality, and also helps.

Comment: Use Holder's inequality with $f=|X_n-X|$ and $g=1$.

Comment: Hi @nicomezi, thanks for your suggestion, although we haven't studied Holder's inequality in class either, so I was just wondering if there was another way to do it.

Comment: Jensen's inequality then maybe ? $f(E(Z))\le E(f(Z))$ for any convex function $f$.

Comment: @астонвіллаолофмэллбэрг, thanks for your comment! So,  $0 \leq \mathbb{E}[|X_n - X|^2] - \mathbb{E}[|X_n - X|]^2$ and so $\mathbb{E}[|X_n - X|^2] \geq \mathbb{E}[|X_n - X|]^2$?

Comment: Yes , that is correct, so what do you see from here? Write an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We know that $\mathbb{E}[|X_n - X|^2] \rightarrow 0$ as $n \rightarrow \infty$ and we want to show that $\mathbb{E}[|X_n - X|] \rightarrow 0$.

For any random variable X we know that:
$$ 0 \le Var(X) = \mathbb{E}[X^2] - E[X]^2$$

By this, we can say that 
$$\mathbb{E}[|X_n-X|] \le \sqrt{\mathbb{E}[|X_n-X|^2]}$$

Since $\mathbb{E}[|X_n-X|] \geq 0$, and $\mathbb{E}[|X_n-X|^2]$  goes to zero as $n \rightarrow \infty$. This is enough to prove $L^1$ convergence.